# MYSQL Key creation on new table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to Mysql and I am not sure where to begin but here goes.

I have a database that has a couple of federated RO tables pulling from another database.  I have created a view that uses a common key to link the tables.  The key looks like this "20-2037".  In that view I also have a new RW table that needs to have fields updated in it.  How do I get those key fields into the new table so I can use them as a key?

I inserted the initial keys via query but how do I keep it updated when a new key is added to the federated tables?

Thank you for your patience and let me know what other info would be helpful.

Here is more info.

Federated Table1

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|  FT11   |  FT12   |   Key   |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Value 3 | Value 6 | 20-1123 |
| Value 3 | Value 4 | 20-1128 |
| Value 5 | Value 8 | 20-1121 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Federated Table2

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|  FT21   |  FT22   |   Key   |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Value 3 | Value 1 | 20-1123 |
| Value 4 | Value 4 | 20-1128 |
| Value 6 | Value 3 | 20-1121 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Local Table1(How do I get these keys in here when the Federated Tables have new keys)

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|  LT11   |  LT12   |   Key   |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 | 20-1123 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | 20-1128 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | 20-1121 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

View1

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  FT21   |  FT22   |  LT11   |  LT12   |   Key   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value 3 | Value 1 | Value 3 | Value 1 | 20-1121 |
| Value 3 | Value 1 | Value 3 | Value 1 | 20-1128 |
| Value 3 | Value 1 | Value 3 | Value 1 | 20-1123 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: not sure to understand but you may need to create a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html), which'll update/insert into RW table when key value changes in the RO table(s)...

Comment: can you provide some example with sample data ??